# A way of hiding a div for a set of IP addresses - using javascript

Tags: javascript, ip-address

There are ways of recognising IP addresses from certain countries so I can use `$("#myDiv").hide();` to not show a div when these countries occur.

However, I want to recognise IP addresses from a single company. The company can give me the format of their IP address.

What do I need in javascript? What function tells me their IP in javascript? What part of their IP will pinpoint the company?

It is nothing important. I just want to hide adverts for certain companies using my website. I want to use javascript, but am willing to call a php script on my web server if necessary using ajax which will then be processed in javascript in my webpage.

What can I do?

Comment: Browsers don't usually (AFAIK don't ever) reveal this, so you'll probably have to use an ajax query to some site that gets that on the backend then returns it to you. Since this has some delay I'm guessing you'll have to hide the ad on page load and wait for this to return to decide if you should show it.

Comment: EG. grabbing something like http://httpbin.org/ip on the user's browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a visitor's IP address from javascript in the browser client. However, you can get it from the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header which is sent to your server and then load that into the html/js sent to the visitor browser.. Alternatively, you can send a query to https://jsonip.com from your javascript to get the visitor's IP.